# Python Code for Web proxy server

Tags: python, sockets, client

#**this is a web server code .. it showing serverSocket.blind(('',serverPort))

## AttributeError: '_socketobject' object has no attribute 'blind'**

please help me in this..
from socket import *
    serverPort=8888
    serverSocket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    #Prepare a sever socket

```
serverSocket.blind(('',serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print 'the web server is up on port:', serverPort
while True:
#Establish the connection
    print 'Ready to serve...'
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        print message, '::', message.split()[0], ':', message.split()[1]
        filename = message.split()[1]
        print filename,'||', filename[1:]
        f = open(filename[1:])
        outputdata = f.read()
#Send one HTTP header line into socket
        connectionSocket.send('\nHTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n')
#Send the content of the requested file to the client
        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i])
#Close client socket
            connectionSocket.close()
    except IOError:
        pass            
#Send response message for file not found
        print "404 Not found"
        connectionSocket.send('\HTTP/1.1 404 Not found\n\n')

        break 
    serverSocket.close()
serverPort=8888
serverSocket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
#Prepare a sever socket

serverSocket.blind(('',serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print 'the web server is up on port:', serverPort
while True:
#Establish the connection
    print 'Ready to serve...'
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        print message, '::', message.split()[0], ':', message.split()[1]
        filename = message.split()[1]
        print filename,'||', filename[1:]
        f = open(filename[1:])
        outputdata = f.read()
#Send one HTTP header line into socket
        connectionSocket.send('\nHTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n')
#Send the content of the requested file to the client
        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i])
#Close client socket
            connectionSocket.close()
    except IOError:
        pass            
#Send response message for file not found
        print "404 Not found"
        connectionSocket.send('\HTTP/1.1 404 Not found\n\n')

        break 
    serverSocket.close()
```

Comment: Last time I checked the function was named `bind` not _blind_.

Comment: now it showing more errors......

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Saurabh\workspace\Crawler\WebServer.py", line 7, in <module>

    serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))

  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)

socket.error: [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Comment: Thanks Paulo, it worked but problem is that socket port is 9876 then only it start ready to server.. now still i have the problem with above thing that its showing warning that frist line : from socket import *... how can improve that